# Ionic 4 shadow DOM styling

Tags: angular, ionic4, shadow-dom

Remark: I have checked [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56076485/ionic-4-how-to-change-shadow-dom-in-css) and [this api](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewEncapsulation) from the angular docs which don't help me.

Hi everyone, I am creating an Ionic app whose structure looks something like this:

```
...
<ion-row>
  <ion-col>
    <div>
      Section
    </div>
    <app-custom-component [data]='customData'></app-custom-component>
  </ion-col>
</ion-row>
...
```

In the `app-custom-component` all the html elements are dependent on that `data` input. That's why I have something like this:

```
<ion-content> 
  <div *ngIf="data">
...
```

So far so good, however, the issue is that the shadow-dom creates scrolling behavior adding an extra element like this:

```
#shadow-root(open)
  <style></style>
  <div class="inner-scroll scroll-y"><slot></slot></div>
...
```

which add scrolling behavior and hides all the content that I create inside div with 30px height. I have tried searching for other similar problems or adding `scroll-y: visible !important` to its my divs without success. What could I do to remove the scroll from the element created by the shadow-dom?

Comment: Have you considered not using the ion-content container and just using your own styled div?

Comment: Do you mean like to remove the shadow-root from the DOM? If yes, I have considered it but didn't find a way to do this.

Comment: I mean instead delete <ion-content>..</ion-content> (which is probably creating the styles) and replace it with your own <div></div> that you style as needed.

Comment: It actually just solved my problem! I should have tried it again. I was too focus on the shadow dom. Thanks for the suggestion, if you want you can add an answer and I will accept it. If you want, you could also add information why is the `shadow-dom` added when there is `ion-content`

Comment: @Shannon - You should probably add it as a possible answer.

Comment: Duh! @Shannon's comment made me think, Instead of trying so hard to style the .inner-scroll within the shadow root within the ion-content, all I need to do is place my own div within the ion-content, and put the styles there (then refactor my other elements' display logic)! That avoids all the weird scrolling & content offset issues due to fullscreen content + header + tab bar. Maybe I need a rubber duck.